# Why is this inequality important? $(1+p)^n\geq 1+np$

Tags: inequality

I'm reading Courant's *What is Mathematics?*

In the beginning, he's showing some proofs, there's a proof about **An Important Equality** and this important equality is:

$$(1+p)^n\geq 1+np$$

The book's author states the proof but he doesn't say why the inequality is important, I had a feeling that this inequality importance is by stabilishing the $\geq$ relation in $\mathbb{N}$, is this it's importance? If not, what is it?

Comment: Found it! This was posted yesterday, check out how the first user does this problem in the second option: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854123/prove-if-a1-then-lim-n-rightarrow-inftyan-infty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is usually called [Bernoulli's inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliInequality.html). It frequently appears in mathematical contests. This inequality is important, because many other inequalities can be proved using it. [Here is some person's Bachelor's thesis](http://www.staff.vu.edu.au/RGMIA/monographs/final-carte.pdf) where it is mentioned among others; in particular, reference [60; Zhu H.] seems to offer some explanation with applications, but I could not find an on-line version.

Answer (score 4):

One place it is important in approximation.  When $np \ll 1, (1+p)^n$ is greater than, but close to, $1+np$ as subsequent terms are of order $(np)^2$ and higher.  Another is proving inequalities.  $1+np$ is much simpler and easier to work with than $(1+p)^n$.  If it is not so much smaller that your proposed inequality fails, it often gets you somewhere useful.

Answer (score 2):

It comes up in all kinds of surprising places. It comes from the binomial theorem: $$(1+p)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}p^k$$From which you can easily infer that for any choice of $m\leq n$, $$(1+p)^n\geq \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n}{k}p^k$$

Where in this case we are taking $m=1$.

Just to give you an example, here's a quick proof that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{p}=1$ for $p>1$. Let $x_n=\sqrt[n]{p}-1$ so that $\sqrt[n]{p}=x_n+1$. Then $p=(x_n+1)^n$ and we can use the inequality to obtain 
$$
p=(x_n+1)^n\geq nx_n+1 \\
\frac{p -1}{n}\geq x_n>0
$$

And so $x_n\rightarrow 0$ and $\sqrt[n]{p}=1-x_n\rightarrow1$.

It just comes up in surprising places.

Answer (score 2):

It can be used (as shown in "What is Mathematics") to prove that $n^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ for integer $n$ by starting with $(1+1/\sqrt{n})^n$. This has been discussed here (by me, naturally), so I'll leave the details for the reader.

It can also be used to prove the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality for the case when $n-1$ of the $n$ items are the same. This, in turn, can be used to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$ exists (for integer $n$).